# Mathematical Writing, Style: Contractions

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

I am in the process of finishing up writing my first paper, and I have a question on style.

> How much should contractions be avoided? Specifically, should "we'll" be avoided?

Having looked online, it appears that a lot of people don't like them, at all. However, with my years and years of experience that comes with $1$yr of PhD (=P) I feel that this may be too broad a rule.

I agree that writing some contractions, for example *"this won't be able to..."* is likely to be a not a good idea. However, I feel that the case of "we'll" is more subtle. Either one has to write "we shall" everywhere, which seems overly formal and/or old-fashioned, or write "we will". While I agree that language evolves over time, "we will" is very unnatural to say -- specifically the two w-s in close succession; other languages get around this with apostrophes also, for example saying "l'acqua" in Italian, rather than "la acqua". Sometimes "we will" is better, eg if you want to emphasise that you will, or just reply "yes, we will" -- hopefully no-one replies "yes, we'll"!

I feel that a paper should be written so that it reads as fluidly as possible, putting all the focus on the actual maths. As such, using "we'll" sometimes (not necessarily always) seems far preferable.

I'd be interested to know if I'm the only one that feels this way, and to be advised on how to use this! (Being a native (British) English speaker myself, I also can't comment on what it's like to read "we will" as a non-native.)

Comment: I suggest that instead of worrying about this, you worry about avoiding the passive voice: "How much should contractions be avoided? " => "Should I avoid 'we'll' in my mathematical writing?"  :)

Comment: To whoever voted to close, instead of doing this without leaving a comment to suggest improvement, can you explain how I should edit my question so that you feel it is more appropriate for the site? Under the tag `article-writing` is written this: "Various aspects of writing mathematics such as style, notation, grammar, frequently used phrases and common mistakes". To me, my question appears to fit that perfectly

Comment: @JohnHughes I only added in the specific bit about "we'll" after. I'm not sure passive voice is an issue though: this website is supposed to be a resource for other people, not just for me to have a specific question answered (at least I hope my question can help others!) :)

Comment: (Btw, though sometimes passive voice is silly, it is harmless.)

Comment: One point.  A mathematics publication will (we hope) be read also by those whose English is weak.  So writing "we will" and not "we'll" is a small price to pay to increase comprehension for those readers.  It is much more important than whether "we will" sounds stilted or formal.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This to me seems to be the only real reason for using "we will" rather than "we'll": people not confident in English will find it easier to understand. It seems to be the only real reason... but it a pretty strong reason! That said, there has to be a balance with all these things, and the question is which side of the balance is this :)

Comment: I've gotten feedback to the effect that "we will" and "we'll" are *both* to be avoided. Unless you're actually talking about future research, your paper should stay in present tense and say "we prove Lemma 39 in section 17" rather than "we *will* prove Lemma 39 in section 17".

Comment: Interesting, and good advice in general, but maybe a bit too sweeping? For example, "[... defines f(x) previously...] Let $\epsilon> 0$. We'll choose $\epsilon$ so that $f(\epsilon) > 1$." If one can see immediately how to choose $\epsilon$, then "we'll" could be replaced with "we"; however, if we need to to some work in order to find out what $\epsilon$ should be, using the present tense suggests (to me, at least) that we do it right then; the "we'll" shows that we have to do some work to find out what $\epsilon$ should be.

Comment: This situation probably doesn't arise that often, and I think that in general yours is a good rule of thumb :)

Answer (score 2):

Non-native english speaker here, with a bit more experience than you but not that much.

I don't think you can go wrong with being formal when you write mathematics. Phrases like "hence", "thus", "We shall see that..." are kind of common (though "hence" and "shall" are probably near the upper limit).

"We will" doesn't sound strange to me, but again I am not a native speaker.